# submit onchange using request mapping in spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Generating a Jasper report depending on the user selected values from drop down (have two drop downs).

**JSP:**

```
<form:form name="f" action="${flowExecutionUrl}"  modelAttribute="simpleReportSelector">
    <table class="search">
        <tr><th colspan="3"><fmt:message key="report.someextract"/></th></tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b><fmt:message key="somereport.sortdate"/></b>         
                <select id="firstfield" name="localDate" onchange="this.form.reloadPage.value='true';submit()"> 
                    <c:forEach var="dl" items="${dateList}">    
                        <c:if test="${dl.selected==false}"> 
                            <option value="${dl.itemValue}">${dl.itemLabel}</option>
                        </c:if>

                        <c:if test="${dl.selected==true}">  
                            <option selected="selected"  value="${dl.itemValue}">${dl.itemLabel}</option>
                        </c:if>                                                         
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>   
            </td>

            <td><input type="hidden" id="reloadPage" name="reloadPage" value=""/></td>

            <td><b><fmt:message key="somereport.equipNumber"/></b>
                <select id="uld" name="uldNumber"> 
                    <c:forEach var="u" items="${uldList}">  
                        <option value="${u.itemValue}">${u.itemLabel}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td class="right" colspan="3"><button type="submit" name="_eventId_exportReport">Submit</button></td></tr>

        <tr class="hide">
            <td><input id="submithidden" type="submit" value="submithidden" name="_eventId_submitButton" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

When user selects this particular menu from header, page populates with `datelist` and `uldlist`. `datelist` will be defaulted to today date and `uldlist` with 'select'. When user selects a previous date or future date, `uldlist` supposed to populate with different list.

**controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/uldReport.do")
public class ULDReport {
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @RequestMapping(value="/uldReport.do",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        //code to populate datelist and uld list(populates using present day)

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @RequestMapping(params={"reloadPage='true'"}, value="/uldReport.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setUpUld(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        //this should populate the uld list by using the date seelcted by user

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @RequestMapping(params={"reloadPage='false'"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processSubmit(@ModelAttribute SimpleReportSelector simpleReportSelector, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws IOException{
        //some code
    }
}
```

First method works good, but when I change the date, app directs to an error page. I think may be something with `@RequestMapping`, if I remove `params` from second and third method in controller, app submits with `processandsubmit`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "app crashes"? Do you get an error? It would help if you could post the stack trace.

Comment: directs to an error page and there is no error..even tuned on all my traces, debug and warn in log4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be happening because of the way the URL is constructed. The fact that the page is loading a blank page means that it can't find anything that matches the criteria you have set up, and so it's silently failing.

For it to work as you expect, chances are you need to have the url formatted something like this:

`/uldReport.do?reloadPage=true`

or

`/uldReport.do/reloadPage/true`

depending on your setup.

But the point is that it needs to be in the URL and not a submitted field in your form, which it seems like it is right now.

Comment: i think `params` will append at the end of the path. which makes like the one you explained

Comment: Yes, most likely. Give it a try and write back with your results.